# Batch error "( unexpected" if statement nested inside for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, if-statement

I wrote this small script to kill Spotify whenever the title of the window is "Advertisement". For now, it just looks for the `spotify.exe` process and, if the name of the window matches, kills it (next step is executing it every second). However, I get an error every time I execute it, telling me that there's an unexpected `(` in `IF /i "%A:~0,4" (`, but such statement is not in my code: it seems like Windows modifies `IF /i "%%A:~0,4%"=="PID:" (` before executing it.

Here's the script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

tasklist /fi "imagename eq spotify.exe" /fo list /v > tmp.txt

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A IN ("tmp.txt") DO (
  SET test=%%A
  echo %%A
  IF /i "%%A:~0,4%"=="PID:" (
    SET "pid=%%A:PID:          =%"
    echo %pid%
  )
  IF /i "%%A:~0,13%"=="Window Title:" (
    SET "wintitle=%%A:Window Title: =%"
    echo %wintitle%
  )
  IF "%wintitle%"=="Advertisement" (
    taskkill /F /PID %pid%
  )
)

PAUSE
```

Error message (with `echo` on):

```
C:\Users\marco\Desktop>antispotify.bat

C:\Users\marco\Desktop>tasklist /fi "imagename eq spotify.exe" /fo list /v  1>tmp.txt
( was unexpected at this time.
C:\Users\marco\Desktop>  IF /i "%A:~0,4" (
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: substring substituiion with `for` variables doesn't work. Ise your `test` variable instead, together with [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task to force a real kill of Spotify process running for advertisement can be done also by using following batch file without using [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "imagename eq spotify.exe" /FO LIST /V 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%~I" == "PID" (
        for /F %%K in ("%%~J") do set "ProcessIdentifier=%%~K"
    ) else if /I "%%~I" == "Window Title" (
        for /F "tokens=*" %%K in ("%%~J") do if /I "%%~K" == "Advertisement" call %SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /F /PID %%ProcessIdentifier%%
    )
)
endlocal
```

The same code with using delayed environment variable expansion:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "imagename eq spotify.exe" /FO LIST /V 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%~I" == "PID" (
        for /F %%K in ("%%~J") do set "ProcessIdentifier=%%~K"
    ) else if /I "%%~I" == "Window Title" (
        for /F "tokens=*" %%K in ("%%~J") do if /I "%%~K" == "Advertisement" %SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /F /PID !ProcessIdentifier!
    )
)
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `taskkill /?`
- `tasklist /?`

See also: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, substring manipulation doesn't work on `for` variables (`%%a` type). Instead, you need an ordinary variable and of course [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028).

But may I suggest another approach:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 
for /f "tokens=2,9 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" /fo csv /v /nh') do (
   set "pid=%%~a"
   set "wintitle=%%~b"
)
set pid
set wintitle
IF "%wintitle%"=="Advertisement" taskkill /F /PID %pid%
```

Here we use the command directly with the `for` loop instead of using a temporary file. Besides that, we change the output format to `csv` (easier to parse) with no header line ( `/nh`)

( I used `notepad.exe`, because I don't have spotify, but that's easy to adapt)